# Can I use CSS to inject a band of colour before the div?

Tags: html, css, page-break-before

Take this HTML snippet (I don't want to change the HTML syntax if possible):

```
<div class="containerMeeting" style="page-break-before: always">
</div>
```

In screen mode I would like a think grey band to be displayed before the `div` to mimic a page break. Print mode would not show it.

Can I use any CSS to produce this behaviour?

To clarify, I only want this band of colour if I have specified the page break property.

Comment: You can use the @media print query to apply styling only to print mode, e.g. hide the grey band. Also, consider using a class, e.g. .page-break so you can easily re-use the page-break-before styling across elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `::before` pseudo-element, given that the HTML content remains consistent:

```css
[style*="page-break-before"]::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Try it:

```css
[style*="page-break-before"]::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
Barfoo<div class="containerMeeting" style="page-break-before: always">
Foobar</div>
```

Comment: I wrapped it in `@media screen` block. All good!